# how to fix built path error in eclipse while creating a project in new workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: Whenever I try to create a workspace in eclipse this error pops up]

I can no longer create a new workspace has everytime I do so this error pops up when creating a project.
My old workspace works fine though.

I assume it's because of library as my old workspace and new workspace has different library.

**Built path of the second image is the faulty one.**

[image: Old workspace library]
[image: Faulty new workspace library]
[image: Installed jre's]

Comment: You have to configure the JRE/JDK in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ to be able to use it in the _Java Build Path_.

Comment: How do I configure it?

Comment: I just added new JRE and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **add the JDK** (or JRE, but then you don't see the source code) in ***Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs*** first to be able to use the JRE system library in the Java Build Path.

Comment: I have added the picture of preferences>installed JRE'S dialog box(LAST PICTURE). The error was caused because it only had jdk13.0.1 in the installed JREs. But shouldn't JDK 13 come with it's own JRE? Now I am confused about JDK and JRE. The problem was solved when I added JRE 1.6.0.

Comment: Since Java 9 the idea (of Oracle) is to use `jlink` to create a Java application containing the required parts of the JRE. But if using `jlink`, the application cannot have extensions/plugins since they might require the missing JRE parts. In contrast to Oracle, [AdoptOpenJDK still provides JREs as separate downloads](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html) (since Java 9 a JDK does not contain a JRE anymore as it was before for up to Java 8 for JDKs from Oracle).